# Как правильно переносить строку в словаре по правилам PEP8?

Tags: python, pep8

дан словарь, т.к. максимум в строку вроде допускается 150 символов, то нужно ее перенести , но как я понимаю в конце строки нужно поставить какой-то знак для переноса

пытался разными слешами, но пишет что все равно ошибка

```
lau = {'Петер Хандке': '2019', 'Светлана Алексеевич': '2015',
            'Патрик Модиано': '2014', 'Элис Энн Манро': '2013', 'Мо Янь':
            '2012', 'Тумас Транстремер': '2011', 'Марио Варгас Льоса': '2010',
            'Герта Мюллер': '2009', 'Жан-Мари Гюстав Леклезио': '2008',
            'Дорис Лессинг': '2007', 'Орхан Памук': '2006', 'Гарольд Пинтер':
            '2005', 'Эльфрида Елинек': '2004', 'Джон Максвелл Кутзее': '2003',
            'Имре Кертес': '2002', 'Видиадхар Сураджпрасад Найпол': '2001',
            'Гао Синцзянь': '2000', 'Гюнтер Грасс': '1999', 'Жозе Сарамаго':
            '1998', 'Дарио Фо': '1997', 'Вислава Шимборска': '1996',
            'Шеймус Хини': '1995', 'Кэнзабуро Оэ': '1994', 'Тони Моррисон':
            '1993', 'Дерек Уолкотт': '1992', 'Надин Гордимер': '1991'}
```

Comment: речь идет о переносе одной строки или ключей и значений словаря целиком, не разбивая строки в ключах и значениях? И откуда взялось значение 150 символов? В [PEP8 максимальная длина строки определяется в 79 символов](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

Comment: @MaxU речь идет о правильном переносе строк, т.е. по правилам PEP8 , ибо так как сейчас в примере выдает ошибку
а про 150 символов ошибся, теперь буду знать что 79

Comment: для справки: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431862/python-bracket-convention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне кажется правильней будет записывать каждую пару ключ и значения в новой строке

```
lau = {
    'Петер Хандке': '2019',
    'Светлана Алексеевич': '2015',
    'Патрик Модиано': '2014',
    'Элис Энн Манро': '2013',
    'Мо Янь': '2012',
    'Тумас Транстремер': '2011',
    'Марио Варгас Льоса': '2010',
    'Герта Мюллер': '2009',
    'Жан-Мари Гюстав Леклезио': '2008',
    'Дорис Лессинг': '2007',
    'Орхан Памук': '2006',
    'Гарольд Пинтер': '2005',
    'Эльфрида Елинек': '2004',
    'Джон Максвелл Кутзее': '2003',
    'Имре Кертес': '2002',
    'Видиадхар Сураджпрасад Найпол': '2001',
    'Гао Синцзянь': '2000',
    'Гюнтер Грасс': '1999',
    'Жозе Сарамаго': '1998',
    'Дарио Фо': '1997',
    'Вислава Шимборска': '1996',
    'Шеймус Хини': '1995',
    'Кэнзабуро Оэ': '1994',
    'Тони Моррисон': '1993',
    'Дерек Уолкотт': '1992',
    'Надин Гордимер': '1991'
}
```

Comment: Всё же тут вопрос не **как Вам кажется**, а как правильно по PEP8. И стоило бы подкрепить ссылкой на соответствующий раздел. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Answer (score 7):

Маленькое дополнение к ответу @Danis - хорошим стилем и хорошей привычкой считается указание запятой после **последнего** значения словаря, списка или кортежа.

```
items = {
    "string1": "val1",
    "last string": "val",
    # ------------------^ 
}
```

Это гармонизирует строки, позволяет легче добавлять новые значения и эта привычка позволит избежать классической ошибки - когда по ошибке создается скалярное значение вместо кортежа, состоящего из **единственного** элемента:

```
values = (123, )
#  ----------^
```

Если не указать запятую в конце - получим скаляр вместо кортежа:

```
In [145]: values = (123)

In [146]: type(values)
Out[146]: int          #  <---- NOTE!!!

In [147]: values = (123, )

In [148]: type(values)
Out[148]: tuple
```